# overlay footer over div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried to create a overlaying footer by adding position:absolute to #container & a Top: XXpx to .panel2 as well as adding a z-index however this does not work any help is greatly appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/z3q2wtLf/29/embedded/result/

below is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish

```css
div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

#div1 {
    background-color: red;
}

#div2 {
    background-color: blue;
    top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle link doesn't work - jsfiddle says the page doesn't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<div2>` would be the footer? In this case, *only* `<div2>` has to get the `position: absolute` setting. Also, as @Yaakov already wrote, the surrounding container has to have `position: relative`.

A very basic setup would be:

```
<div class="wrap_all">
  <div class="content">
    (content text text text)
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    (footer text)
  </div>
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
.wrap_all {
    position: relative;
}
.content {
    background: red;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

(The `margin-bottom: 50px;` on `.content` is there so that no text or images in `.content` can be hidden by the footer)

Answer (score 1):

Your #div1 and #div2 should be wrapped within an element with relative position in order to work.

For example:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
#container {
  position:relative;
}
#div1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: blue;
  top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: The example already works, however when I apply this concept  to the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/z3q2wtLf/29/light/embedded/result/ it doesn't work? I also tried wrapping panel2 inside the #container to apply the positioning and this did not work either